# Maple complex exponential form to algebraic.

Tags: complex-numbers, maple

How can I easily convert complex number from exponential or trigonometric form to algebraic?

**Update**

In fact I'm trying to simplify this expression:
[image: exoression]

The only way I see is to convert to trigonometric form then expand but I can't make Maple calculate cos and sin. So how can I do this?

My code:

```
restart; w1 := 100; L2 := 100*10^(-3); L3 := L2; L5 := 200*10^(-3); C6 := (200/3)*10^(-6); psi1 := 32.5 degrees;
Z6 := -I/(w1*C6);
Z5 := I*w1*L5;
Z2 := I*w1*L2;
Z1 := 75;
Z3 := I*w1*L3;
Z4 := 75;
Z7 := 75;
eq := {Imk-(U1-U2)/Z2-(U2-U3)/Z1 = 0, U1/Z4+U1/(Z5+Z6+Z7)+U3/Z3 = 0, (U1-U2)/Z2-U1/(Z5+Z6+Z7)-U1/Z4 = 0};

a := solve(eq, {U1, U2, U3});
U1 := eval(U1, a);
U1 := convert(U1, float);

Imk1 := [.575, .868*exp(I*psi1), -.366, .243, -.183];
Ink := Array(1 .. 5);

for n to 5 do 
    Ink[n] := simplify((32.14738845-6.185240008*I)*Imk1[n]/(Z5+Z6+Z7))     
end do; 

Ud := 0; 
for n to 5 do: 
     Ud := Ud+(1/2)*Ink[n]^2 
end do;

Ud := simplify(sqrt(Ud), sqrt);

print(Ink[2]); 
expand(convert(Ink[2], trig));
```

Comment: Can you give an example what you actually mean by algebraic?

Comment: @MrYouMath I mean a+i*b. In Russia we call it algebraic form ;)

Comment: The $z=a+i*b$ form has no real name as far as I know. Some call it cartesian, rectangular or coordinate form. And now I learned that it is also called algebraic (the question is why is the polar form not algebraic :D)?

Comment: @MrYouMath No, I'm just trying to get that form ;) I need top expression become a+i*b without sin and cos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z=|z|\exp(i\phi)=|z|\left(\cos \phi+i\sin \phi\right)=|z|\cos \phi +i|z|\sin \phi$$

Hence $x=|z|\cos \phi$ and $y = |z|\sin \phi$.

This is one way to do it in Maple:

```
G:=1+2*I;
#convert cartesian to polar
G__polar:=convert(G,polar);
#convert polar to cartesian
G__cartesian:=evalc(G__polar);
```

Comment: Yes, yes, I know it. Sorry for mess. See update(image seems bad but you can click on it). Thanks.

Comment: Yours and mine approaches give me the same result. Is it possible to make Maple to calculate cos and sin in that expression?

Comment: Right click and select approximate with your desired precission.

Comment: Nope, it's doesn't help. It just cut numbers tails but sin and cos are still here.

Comment: can you post your maple code?

Comment: Sure. See update.

Comment: Your problem is the 32.5 degrees convert them into radiants and dont use a unit.

Comment: Oohhh, thanks a lot. I was mad with that.  It seems really weird. Why can't it use degrees? I don't like them either but the task has them and... And thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code posted here as plaintext code contains the following statement,

```
psi1 := 32.5 degrees;
```

That is not valid 1D Maple Notation code. In typeset 2D Input that space between `32.5` and `degrees` can mean implicit multiplication, and perhaps that's what you meant here too. As plaintext 1D Maple Notation that is invalid syntax, however. You can get a great deal of confusion by pasting snippets of 2D Input as (ostensible) fragments of plaintext 1D Maple Notation code. Please clarify it for us.

If your actual code is simply using the name `degrees` as if it were any other name, like, say,

```
psi1 := 32.5*degrees;
```

then you can replace that name within `Ink` with a command like,

```
subs(degrees=Pi/180, Ink);
```

And of course you can evaluate that to floating-point, as say,

```
evalf(subs(degrees=Pi/180, Ink));
```

Note that the name `degrees` does not have much special meaning in Maple, and certainly does not mean units of arc-degree, in general. You can get a limited amount of use out of the `Unit(degree)` construct, however. Try you code with, say,

```
psi1 := 32.5 * Unit(degrees);
```

and see the effect. The `simplify` command knows how to combine and (sometimes) resolve dimensions for simplifying expressions involving `Unit`s. See also the `Units,Standard` help-page.

Comment: Didn't know it. In math notation there was no it but here it appeared. This confused me and I deleted multiplication symbol after pasting the text here.